# Looking for something like fetch_add for atomic<double>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm looking for some sort of an add-operation working on atomic doubles.
Sadly:

```
myatomdouble += toadddouble;
```

isn't defined,

```
myatomdouble = myatomdouble + toadddouble;
```

gets screwed by multithreading and fetch_add is only available for integral types, but not for doubles. But something like fetch_add would be exactly what I need. :(

and mutexing every attempt to modify the variable makes the program superslow, the code unreadable and destroys the idea of atomic.

So is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You implement this the way you implement any atomic modification to generic objects.

```
template<typename T>
T atomic_fetch_add(std::atomic<T> *obj, T arg) {
  T expected = obj->load();
  while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(obj, &expected, expected + arg))
    ;
  return expected;
}
```

Although there's no guarantee that `atomic<double>` doesn't use mutexes, so you'd have to check your implementation.