# Count the duration of a task inside a method called by multiple threads simultaneously

Tags: c++, c++11

I have created a member function that is called by a number of threads at the same time. Inside this function I want to count the total duration of the execution of a function . The problem is that if  I create 4 threads for example, the time I get back is 4 times the actual time! How can I get the actual time? My method looks like this:

```
void Class1::myTask() {

//...code

chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

theFunction();

chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
chrono::duration<double> time_span = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(end - start);
mytime = time_span.count();  // mytime is of atomic type

setTheTime(mytime); 

//...more code
} 

// The method to set the Total Time
void Class1::setTheTime(double mTime){
  time = time + mTime; // time is of atomic type
}
```

This method is called for a very large number of times, so everytime the "end - start" returns something like 0.000897442 sec. The total duration is about 11 sec, but `time` is ending as something like 44 seconds!

Here is an example of code that works so that you can see the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

atomic<double> time1;
atomic<double> mytime;

void theFunction() {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        x++;
    }
}

double setTheTime(double mTime1) {
    time1 = time1 + mTime1;
}

void countTime() {

    chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    theFunction();

    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double> time_span = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(end - start);
    mytime = time_span.count();

    setTheTime(mytime);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    vector<thread> threads;
    long double mt;

    chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        threads.push_back(thread(countTime));

    for (auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double> time_span = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(end - start);
    mt = time_span.count(); // mytime is of atomic type
    cout << "Time out of the function: " << mt * 1000 << endl;
    cout << "Time inside the function: " << time1 * 1000 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `time = time + mTime;` is valid, even with an atomic type, but I'm uncertain if `time += mTime` is any better

Comment: relevent, I find parameters with a leading `m` prefix confusing, and expect them to be members.

Comment: sorry about the prefixes. "time" and "mytime" are of double type. Why can this be a problem? (if i add up the numbers i mean?)

Comment: If all four threads call setTheTime at the same time with the values 100, 105, 200, 196, then it's theoretically possible they all load `time` (which is zero), add their value and then save the sum to `time`, in which case, the end value of `time` is merely the last to be saved.  However, this should result in a _quarter_ of the time being reported, not 4x.  I can't think of a way for a atomic time to get 4x the value.

Comment: im counting the duration of the entire method also, so thats how i know. But i want to be very specific with these results..

Comment: Can you tell us a sample of what the four `mTime` values are and what `time` starts and ends as?

Comment: this method is called for a very large number of times, so everytime the "end - start" returns something like: 0.000897442 sec that is also assigned in mTime. The total duration is about 11 sec (for this amount of data) but i get something like 44 . (Sorry, i think you made a different question, let me check if i can get these numbers)

Comment: also , if i move my code inside mutex, everything works fine.

Comment: @MooingDuck Is correct, `time = time + mTime;` is not an atomic read-modify-write operation. `time += mTime;` *is* an atomic read-modify-write operation. Unfortunately, `operator+=` isn't defined for the generic `std::atomic<T>` template - only for the integral specializations thereof. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137933/looking-for-something-like-fetch-add-for-atomicdouble) for more info.

Comment: You can avoid the `atomic<double>` issue completely by using an integral type for `time`: `std::atomic<std::chrono::steady_clock::rep>` would likely be ideal.

Comment: Marcus, would mind providing a SSCCE? Mock "theFunction" e.g. by filling a vector from rng.

Comment: I posted sample of code that work so that you can see the problem. Couldn't get "atomic<std::chrono::steady_clock::rep>" to work yet..

Comment: also tried with atomic_fetch_add() from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137933/looking-for-something-like-fetch-add-for-atomicdouble?answertab=active#tab-top) but nothing.. same problem again

Answer (score 0):

Let there be N threads, which run in parallel during X seconds natural time.

So for the time S they accumulate
S = N * X

roughly holds.

And 44s indeed equals  4 * 11s .

So what is the problem? :)

Comment: the actuall total time is 11 sec (4* 2,75) not 44

Comment: The "total time" you're referring to is like taken from your wrist watch. Such a watch "runs" single threaded. 4 threads in real parallel execution. like on multiple cores, have "lived" a **cumulative** total of 4 times of that meanwhile. That's just real multi-threading.

Comment: so i guess the thing i want to achieve, cant be done.. That's a pity. One last thing i found can be seen here [link](http://www.gockelhut.com/c++/articles/stopwatch). I run it but something similar happened as above (although it says that it is multithreading-safe)

Comment: I didn't imply that you cannot achieve want you "want". I just tried to show that "problem" is in fact none. Of course you can profile on a per-thread basis - simply use one time accumulator **per thread**. E.g. array<double,N> or std::valarray<double>(N), the latter if you want the # of threads dynamic.